# How can I translate &#039; into an apostrophe in xslt

Tags: xslt, translate

The relevant parts of the code:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="and" select='"&#039;"' />

<xsl:value-of select="translate(products_name/node(),$and,$apos)"/>
```

I'm thinking this should be a simple thing and that the above code should work but it doesn't effect the output at all.

(I used variables because names cannot begin within an ampersand and using just an apostrophe brings up a compile error.)

I've tested the code to make sure the translate is working using strings and there are no errors there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: &#039; is already an apostrophe isn't it?

Comment: yes; I did wonder if the preceding `0` might make it treat it as octal, but then I saw the `9` and did a self face-palm.

Comment: Yes but the string "&amp;#039;" was being displayed instead of an apostrophe. Problem solved now, thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but not yet there: Your problem is, that XSL is a language that itself is written using XML. For **all** XML languages, the parser automatically decodes XML entities. The XSLT engine only comes afterwards.

As a result, the XSLT engine neither does nor can distinguish whether you wrote `'` or `&#039;` - it's the same. For your problem, this has two effects:

1. You have to use a variable containing the apostrope - this is because the apostrophe itself is reserved for string literals in expressions that may contain functions. Even for `<xsl:value-of select="translate(products_name/node(),$and,'&#039;')"/>`, the XML parser transforms the entity into an apostrophe, i.e. `<xsl:value-of select="translate(products_name/node(),$and,''')"/>`
2. You have to escape the ampersand used in the string you search for: for the XSL engine, the variable "and" contains the value `'`, i.e. you are replacing an apostrophe with an apostrophe.

Working solution:

```
<xsl:variable name="apos">'</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select='translate(text(), "&amp;#039;", $apos)'/>
```

Comment: that worked but not directly. I had to put "&amp;#039;" as a variable otherwise I got an error, but my problem is now solved. Thanks you.

Comment: Okay, although I tried and tested it using MSXSL 4.0, different engines may have different opinions of what is a valid function argument.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there's no difference in any XML between `&apos;`, `&#39;` and `&#x27;`, they're different ways of representing exactly the same thing. Therefore, that `translate` call shouldn't do anything.

It depends on how you're transforming it, where that output is (attribute value or element?), and how the output is serialized to text, but your problem isn't with your XSLT.