# xmlstarlet - removing linefeed

Tags: xml, linux, xmlstarlet

I have the following file `log.xml`:

```
<entry>
  <message>Line 1
  Line 2 and so on</message>
</entry>
```

On CentOS 5.4 using xmlstarlet 1.0.1 if I run the following command, while removing linefeed in `message`:

```
xml sel -t -m //entry -v "translate(message,'&#xa;' ,'@')" log.xml
```

The result is:

```
Line 1@  Line 2 and so on
```

On CentOS 6 using xmlstarlet:

```
1.3.1
compiled against libxml2 2.7.6, linked with 20706
compiled against libxslt 1.1.26, linked with 10126
```

I'll receive:

```
Line 1
  Line 2 nd so on
```

Note "and" converted to nothing. I suppose it's not problem of xmlstarlet, but rather some change in libxslt.

Any ideas how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Added problem with transform of letter "a" to nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6651469/825783 might be relevant.

Comment: @EeroHelenius Not sure it's the same problem :(

Comment: Don't know for sure, but maybe the line endings are other than you expect: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28142284

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this in a general way by defining a variable containing the value of a line break:

```
--var linebreak -n --break
```

Then use that variable as the second argument of the translate function:

```
xml sel -t -m //entry
        --var linebreak -n --break
        -v "translate(message, \$linebreak ,'@')"
        log.xml
```

Comment: Wouldn't `translate(message, '\n', ' ')` or `normalize-space(message)` suffice? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550652/428804

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about xmlstarlet, but you could try [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel log.xml -e '//message/translate(., $line-ending, "@")'
```

I wrote all of it, from parser to query engine, so it has no dependencies and behaves the same on all systems.

Answer (score 3):

`&#xa;` only represents a newline character when the XPath expression is itself in an XML file (such as an XSLT stylesheet).  I suspect what's happening here is that when you say

```
translate(message,'&#xa;' ,'@')
```

on the command line, the `'&#xa;'` is being treated as a five character string, and thus you're telling `translate` to replace `&` with `@` and also to replace all of `#`, `x`, `a` and `;` with nothing.

Try a literal newline using ctrl-V

```
xml sel -t -m //entry -v "translate(message,'<ctrl-V><CR>' ,'@')" log.xml
```

(i.e. press ctrl-V followed by carriage return when typing the command - it will appear on your screen as `^M`).

Comment: You are right - &#xa; interpreted as 5 characters. Solution you've proposed not working

Comment: @dimba I'd go with Pablo's answer using a variable.