# Proper formatting to .csv when using xmlstarlet -f

Tags: xml, linux, bash, shell, xmlstarlet

I have the following command:

```
cat PathFiles.txt | xargs xml sel -T -t -f -m /XML/Path -v "concat(value1,',',value2)" -n > test.csv
```

PathFiles.txt contains .xml files

```
COLORADO.xml
ALASKA.xml
CALIFORNIA.xml
WASHINGTON.xml
OREGON.xml
```

It will output like so:

```
#test.csv
COLORADO.xmlvalue1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
ALASKA.xmlvalue1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
...etc
```

My issue is `COLORADO.xmlvalue1,value2` `ALASKA.xmlvalue1,value2` when I need it to be

```
COLORADO.xml 
value1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
ALASKA.xml
value1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
value1,value2
```

Referencing back to the `xml sel -f` is used to output the filename, I feel like I need a newline(?) between what I want to seperate.. I tried `-f \n` but that did not work, then I found out that I am already using the newline `-n` command at the end the `xml sel` command. Is this possible? Should I look into possibly outputting to .txt and the using grep or awk to seperate it out?

Comment: [Look here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952640/xmlstarlet-removing-linefeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Referencing back to the `xml sel -f` is used to output the filename, I feel like I need a newline(?) between what I want to seperate.. I tried `-f \n` but that did not work, then I found out that I am already using the newline `-n` command at the end the `xml sel` command.

Just put another `-n` command after the `-f`:

```
< PathFiles.txt xargs xml sel -T -t -f -n -m /XML/Path -v "concat(value1,',',value2)" -n > test.csv
```